# PHP - how to test web service without calling it?

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I have a PHP web app which calls several SOAP web services. I want to test the app without actually calling the web services. So far I found approach using getMockFromWsdl() and PHPUnit which basically do something like this:

```
$soapClientMock = $this->getMockFromWsdl('test.wsdl', 'TestClass');
$request = 'soap request';

$soapClientMock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('someMethod')
    ->with($this->equalTo($request))
    ->will($this->returnValue('soap response'));

$this->assertEquals( 'soap response', $soapClientMock->someMethod($request) );
```

Is this the best and easiest way to test web services ?